# set imageUrl in gridView by activeRecord attribute values

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I'm trying to set the source of an image in my gridView dynamically through active record attributes. my scenario is that I want to have a switch button for ignoring and un-ignoring some of user information. there is two diffrent image whit names `accept1.png` and `accpt0.png` and I have an attribute in my database named as `is_ignored` which can takes the values between `0` and `1`. What I want to do is that setting the source of image button in grid view by using this attribute.for example if `is_ignored` is equal to `0` shows `accept0.png` and if it's `1` shows `accept1.png`. I want to do something like this :

```
array(
                        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                        'template' => '{acceptStatus}',
                        'header' => Yii::t('app', 'Accept status'),
                        'buttons' => array(
                            'acceptStatus' => array(
                                'url' => "CController::createUrl('/mycontroller/myaction' , array('id'=>\$data->id,'f'=>'1'))",
                                'imageUrl' => "/themes/negin/images/accept\$data->is_ignored.png",
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
```

is there any suggestion for me?

Comment: 'imageUrl' => '/themes/negin/images/accept'.$data->is_ignored.'.png',

Answer (score 0):

you must understand that `$data` is only available on runtime of the widget, so your code must be eval'ed

It sounds like you want this :

```
'url' => 'CController::createUrl("/mycontroller/myaction" , array("id"=>$data->id,"f"=>"1"))',
'imageUrl' => '"/themes/negin/images/accept".$data->is_ignored.".png"',
```